# Android set EditText to show caps but keep original user input values

Tags: android, android-edittext, uppercase

How can I show the text in an `EditText` as all caps, but save the original input of the user?

I have tried playing around with `InputFilter`s but no luck.

Any leads?

**EDIT:**

I am already using the following code:

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

The issue is not displaying capital letters, the issue is keeping the original user's values.

Comment: Sounds like something I would make a subclass of `EditText` for.

Comment: You want to keep if the user types i.e HeLlOwOrLd but shown as HELLOWORLD, am I wrong?

Comment: @Skizo you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on CommonsWare's insight I was able to put together the following implementation. Please note this does not take other languages into account and will be optimized for that later.

You need to setup a `ReplacementTransformationMethod` like so:

```
public class UpperCaseTransformationMethod extends ReplacementTransformationMethod {

    private static final char[] ORIG = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
        'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    private static final char[] REPL = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O',
        'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };


    public UpperCaseTransformationMethod() {}

    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View v) {
        return super.getTransformation(source, v);
    }

    @Override
    public char[] getOriginal() {
        return ORIG;
    }

    @Override
    protected char[] getReplacement() {
        return REPL;
    }

}
```

Then you just simply apply this method to your `EditText` like so:

```
editText.setTransformationMethod(new UpperCaseTransformationMethod());
```

This will show the characters as uppercase to a user but preserver their original inputs.

You can then just obtain the original input by calling:

```
String originalInput = editText.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Create [an implementation of `TransformationMethod`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/TransformationMethod.html), where in `getTransformation()`, you perform your conversion of the input text to all caps. The input text itself is unchanged; your return value from `getTransformation()` is what is shown to the user. The most common `TransformationMethod` is `PasswordTransformationMethod` — it's what gives you the dots when typing in a password.

This could be as simple as creating [a subclass of `ReplacementTransformation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/ReplacementTransformationMethod.html), overriding `getOriginal()` to return letters and `getReplacement()` to return their all-caps equivalents.

Just be a bit careful to take locale into account when implementing this, so that you are handling capitalization in whatever the user's current language is.

Comment: This is more like it, do you have any implementation code for this? First time I am looking into `TransformationMethod`.

Comment: @AndyRoid: Not really. It's a fairly niche situation. Though a quick search on Google turns up https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/widget/AllCapsTransformationMethod.java, which looks like it is what you are after.

Comment: Thanks! This is useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many ways :

If you want to declare it on your `xml` you can do it with this :

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

or

```
android:textAllCaps="true"
```

If you want to put it programmatically you could create a `filter` as follows :

```
Your_Edit_Text.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

And if you want to get what the user typed you can use [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Here's an example to how to do it:

```
Your_Edit_Text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Comment: This is wrong. I am currently using `new InputFilter.AllCaps()` the issue is not displaying caps in the edittext its keeping the original values that the user types. Doing it your way and calling `editText.getText().toString()` will be all caps. I don't know why this is upvoted so much, this is a basic answer, not particularly made for my use case.

Comment: Try looking into CommonWares answer, I am testing it out right now.

Comment: I removed my downvote, but I would like to prevent answers like these because it means users have to sift through other answers to get to the correct one. Please next time read the question more carefully.

Comment: @AndyRoid I didn't know that you allready get the "all letters to caps" and I thought give you an example to how to do it was a good idea... and the `TextWatch` I thought would be useful to read the text written by user. Thanks anyways..

Answer (score 0):

You need a **TextChangedListener** on the EditText. You can do something like this-

```
edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s.length()>0)
            {

            //Handle the text here. 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question. In particular, please explain how this changes what the user sees but does not change the actual value the user enters.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question.